# LTC 2448 analog input voltage range

Tags: voltage, analog, sensor, adc

I use an [LTC2448](https://www.analog.com/en/products/ltc2448.html) ADC for data acquisition, and I noticed that the ADC has a voltage range of -2.5 to 2.5 V, but some of my sensors have a 0 to 3 V or 5 V range.

I am giving the ADC a Vref of 5 V, but it seems to be that there is no way to shift the range from -2.5-2.5 V to 0-5 V. Is there any way of doing this or do I need to consider getting a new ADC?

[image]

Comment: The ADC has a differential input range of +/-2.5V with a 5V reference but neither input can go (much) below GND. Are your inputs actually differential or single-ended, and  if the former, what is the common-mode voltage on the two inputs you are using for each signal? Using Vcc for Vref on a 24 bit converter of this quality seems almost obscene unless you've got an amazingly quiet and reference-derived Vcc.

Answer (score 0):

You can do one of two things, use an attenuator with a gain of 0.5 and use half the range of the ADC (need a low impedance load on your signal, this is the cheap solution).

Use a level shifter with an opamp (need to subtrace 2.5V from the 0 to 5V signal and have a negative rail)

Use the [LTC2498](https://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/2498fg.pdf) which has a 0 to VCC for it's input range.

Answer (score 0):

None of the analogue inputs of this device should ever be negative, and if you are under the impression that input voltage range is -2.5V to +2.5V, you are mistaken.

Safe analogue input potentials on any channel (\$V_{CHn}\$, at pins 8...23) are:

$$ 0V \le V_{CHn} \le V_{CC} $$

In practice this range extends slightly beyond those limits, but I wouldn't recommend going there, since input currents begin to rise when that happens, which will probably ruin conversion accuracy.

The constraint \$-\frac{1}{2}V_{REF} \le V_{IN} \le +\frac{1}{2}V_{REF}\$ is not referring to absolute potentials at any input, it is telling you the maximum and minimum *difference* between the two potentials presented to the ADC for *valid* conversion, and those two values will depend on whether you are operating in single-ended or differential mode.

This is summarised here, an extract from page 6 of the [datasheet](https://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/2444589fc.pdf):

[image]

That means, for example, that if you establish these conditions:

- \$V_{COM} = +2.5V\$ (pin 7)
- \$V_{REF-}=0V\$ (pin 30)
- \$V_{REF+}=+5V\$ (pin 29)
- program all channels as single-ended mode

then you have 16 single-ended channels, or 16 potentials \$V_{CH0}\$ to \$V_{CH15}\$ to convert. For each channel, the potentials presented to the ADC for conversion will be:

$$
\begin{aligned}
V_{IN-} &= V_{COM} = +2.5V \\ \\
V_{IN+} &= V_{CHn} \\ \\
\end{aligned}
$$

The effective ADC input in this scenario, which will be the conversion result, is:

$$
\begin{aligned}
V_{IN} &= V_{IN+} - V_{IN-} \\ \\
&= V_{CHn} - V_{COM}  \\ \\
&= V_{CHn} - 2.5V\\ \\
\end{aligned}
$$

As long as \$0V \le V_{CHn} \le +5V\$, the constraint \$-\frac{1}{2}V_{REF} \le V_{IN} \le +\frac{1}{2}V_{REF}\$ is never violated.

I don't know whether that solves your problem, since you now have conversions results going from -2.5 to +2.5 (scaled digitally, of course), for input potentials between 0V and 5V, and conversion accuracy dependent entirely on the quality of your +2.5V source.

You can of course set \$V_{COM} = 0V\$, though, so conversions are with respect to ground, but you still must never present negative potentials to any input, and input potentials over +2.5V will be flagged as over-range. Damage to the device can only occur if \$V_{CHn}\$ strays outside the range 0V to \$V_{CC}\$, so input potentials between +2.5V and \$V_{CC}\$ are safe, but will be out of the ADC's valid conversion range.

In other words, you may set these conditions:

- \$V_{COM} = 0V\$ (pin 7)
- \$V_{REF-}=0V\$ (pin 30)
- \$V_{REF+}=+5V\$ (pin 29)
- program all channels as single-ended mode

and the ADC will convert this value:

$$
\begin{aligned}
V_{IN} &= V_{IN+} - V_{IN-} \\ \\
&= V_{CHn} - V_{COM}  \\ \\
&= V_{CHn} - 0V \\ \\
&= V_{CHn} \\ \\
\end{aligned}
$$

The conversion will be valid for:

$$ 0V \le V_{CHn} \le +2.5V $$

So, if you adopt this configuration, you may still need to scale your input signals to fit within the range 0V to +2.5V, but no offset would be required.